# Unhandled exception at 0x001e1078 in Dijkstra's_Algorithm.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xbaadf00d

Tags: c++

I'm setting the pointer of the state class to the pointer of the node but I get access violation I don't know what is the problem?

the exception is here :iosfwd

```
static int __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL compare(const _Elem *_First1, const _Elem *_First2,
        size_t _Count)
        {   // compare [_First1, _First1 + _Count) with [_First2, ...)
        return (_CSTD memcmp(_First1, _First2, _Count));
        }
```

my code
in DijkstraState.h

```
void setCurrent(vertex<T>* v)
    {
        current = v ;
    }
```

in graph.h

```
private member: DijkstraState<type>* states ;`
in constructor: states = new DijkstraState<type>();
template <class type>
void graph<type>::add_vertex(vertex<type> input)
{   
    type vertex_data = input.get_data() ;
    //check vertex does not exist
    if(indexes.find(vertex_data) == indexes.end())
    {
        indexes[input.get_data()] = count ;
        vertices[count] = input ;
        states[count].setCurrent(&(vertices[count]));//////////////////////////
        count ++ ;
    }
}
```

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you dereference uninitialized pointer somewhere.

Comment: The function parameter goes out of scope at the end of the function.  You most likely do not want to store a pointer to it.

Comment: if I change &(input) to &(vertices[count]) it causes the same problem @RetiredNinja Ninja

Comment: It's likely that `states[count]` isn't valid, but there isn't enough information to determine that in your code sample.

Comment: I got the problem states[count] was invalid as you said thanks a lot @RetiredNinja    Ninja

Answer (score 1):

`input` is a parameter of your function. You can think of it like a local variable that is initialized with a value passed in from the caller. That parameter variable will go out of scope when your function returns. You are saving a pointer to `input` in your call to `setCurrent`, leaving you with an invalid pointer and undefined behavior if you try to use the pointer after `add_vertex` finishes.

You haven't shown enough code to know how to fix it. I don't know what `states` is for or where `count` comes from or why you need to save a pointer to a variable.

Comment: I have changed &(input) to &(vertices[count])  and I got the same problem int count ;// is for number of vertices in the graph
DijkstraState<type>* states ; //is used to store of variables to help in solving shortest path problem and I need to save pointer to the current vertex of the graph inside it @The Dark